# Showing that if $X\cup Y=\mathbb{R}$ then $\sup X=\inf Y$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Here is the full question because I keep messing up the wording of it:

b) Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $Y\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $X,Y$ are nonempty. If $x\leq y$ for all $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ then $X$ is bounded above, $Y$ is bounded below and $\mathrm{sup} X\leq \mathrm{inf} Y$. **Completed already**

**c)** If the sets $X,Y$ in b) are such that $X\cup Y=\mathbb{R}$ then $\mathrm{sup} X=\mathrm{inf} Y$.

**This is the one I am attempting**

Struggling with this part of the question a bit, I started by assuming that $X, Y$ are nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $X\cup Y=\mathbb{R}$; notice that by the least upper bound/greatest lower bound principles, we can let $\mathrm{sup} X=c$ and $\mathrm{inf} Y=d$ then $c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ so either $c<d, c>d$ or $c=d$ by properties of $\mathbb{R}$...

I was thinking of showing that $c<d$ and $c>d$ cannot be the case by contradiction since there would then exist some element in $X\cup Y$ but not $\mathbb{R}$. Any hints/tips?

Comment: $X=(0,1), Y=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: fixed the title and question; forgot about those assumptions.

Comment: X and Y can't  be both bounded

Comment: I just removed that; apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\sup X, b=\inf Y$, first show $a\ge b$

Assume the opposite, $a<b$, let $c=\frac{a+b}2$, so we have $a<c<b,$ therefore, $c\notin X \cap c\notin Y$, but $c\in \mathbb{R}$, which contradicts with $X\cup Y=\mathbb{R}$.

Next show $a\le b$,

Assume the opposite, $a>b$

So for $\epsilon=\frac{a-b}{2}>0, \exists x\in X, a-x<\epsilon\Rightarrow x>\frac{a+b}2$, but $b<\frac{a+b}2$, so $\frac{a+b}2\in  Y$, which contradicts with
$x\le y, \forall x\in X, \forall y\in Y$

Comment: How did you know that $\exists x\in X$ such that $a-x<\epsilon$?

Comment: because $a=\sup X$

Comment: How does that follow from the fact that $a=\mathrm{sup} X$?

Comment: Is it because there exists $x\in X$ such that $a\leq x$ and since $\epsilon>0$ then $a<\epsilon+x$?

Comment: Recall the definition of the supremum.

Comment: $a=\sup X$ iff $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists x\in X, x>a-\epsilon$ @kman

Answer (score 3):

You already know $\sup X\le\inf Y$, so suppose $\sup X<\inf Y$.  Then there exists $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sup X<a<\inf Y$.  Because of these inequalities $a\not\in X$ and $a\not\in Y$, so $a\not\in X\cup Y$.  But $X\cup Y=\mathbb{R}$ so this is a contradiction.

Comment: You're right! I did not realize that all I had left to show was simply $\mathrm{sup} X\geq \mathrm{inf} Y$